# How to manage online & offline status in quick blox

Tags: webrtc, quickblox

Can we manage **online** & **offline** status on video calling for **QuickBlox**?

```
<script>
var quickblox;
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched and did R&D more on Quickblox for video calling and chat options.
In chat, there is some functionality to show the status online / offline. But in the video call, they did not provide this type of functionality.